# Missing link hint on a tag page

Tags: bug, tags, design

On [a tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/javascript?show=all&sort=recentlyactive), all links have hints, except the "**improve tag info**". Is this intended?

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]